Using small value resistor as a jumper connection
I made a PCB layout where I was planning on using a PCF8575(U7) with 74HC14(U10) logic inverter and ULN2003A(U8), but it wasn't working as expected so I want to swap the PCF with XL9535 or PCA9535 and drive the ULN2003A directly, without the 74HC14.
My question is how should I connect the pins of the not populated 74HC14 chip? Can I use some low value resistors? I thought about 0ohm resistor but they are not in stock anywhere around where I live so can I use something like 2.7ohm or 3.9ohm as jumpers?


You could solder wire offcuts where needed.

Where would you place these jumpers? on HC14 pads instead of HC14 to bypass it?

@Justme exactly, I edited the picture how I imagined it.

@AndrewMorton I could, I was just wondering if I could use these low value resistors because the 0603 would fit nicely.

OK. Have you looked at the data sheets how much ULN2003 needs input current and how much the IO expander can provide? I don't see what could have caused problems in your original design why it did not work well. Perhaps the solution is not to change the expander and remove the HC14.

The problem is in the io expander - when I turn on the outputs, they are acting weird. For example: if I turn on only the P0, I measure only 0.11V and it's rising when I turn on the other outputs continuously. Once all the outputs are on, the voltage is from 1-1.6V on each output, except the P16 and P17 - on these two there is always 0V. After days of googling I ran into a forum where I found out that there is 2 types of these chips - PCF8575 which works with 2.5V to 5V and PCF8575C which works with 4.5V to 5V and I only had 3.3V on my board.

I got mine from aliexpress and they were labeled PCF8575TS but I didn't find specific datasheet for it to check if it could be the version which requires at least 4.5V. Then I remembered that I have a pcf8575 i/o module board from aliexpress, so I checked the IC on it and it was labeled PF575. So I tried to swap it to my board and it worked. So that's why I think that I have the wrong version for my board. Then I find the XL9535 chips which have the exact same footprint, are cheaper and can provide 10mA, so that's why I want to use them.

@Justme and the ULN2003A needs only about 1mA, so I think they are good for my use.

@k0cka The datasheet I have says it needs more than 1mA at 3.8V or so. And it will take up to 2mA with 5V on input.

@Justme I'm looking at this datasheet and in the table 5.6 - input current I see 0.93mA at 3.85V, isnt that about 1.20mA at 3.3V?

@k0cka Judicious use of smooth-jawed pliers, or a hammer, on a piece of solid copper mains wire will give you an 0603 0 ohm resistor, and then you wouldn't have to worry about 2R7 or 3R9 affecting the reliability.
